# Pentaho: Relational database discarding relation while migrating

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pentaho, sql-server-2014-express, pentaho-spoon

From: MS SQL Server 20014
To: My Sql server

migrating a table from MS SQL which is having dependency in another table is happening to MYSQL discarding relation.
Are there any way to create table along with relation.